# Can't use multiple Databases in my django project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-database

I'm trying to use two DBs for my django project. The first one is for authentication etc, the second should hold data sent by the user through a form.

I added the second DB to my **settings.py** file, but i keep getting errors, the most recent one is `(1146, "Table 'dataset.main_SomeModel' doesn't exist")`

Indeed, it looks like my Django project can't interact with the db, since there is no table there.

Am i doing something wrong? Maybe is it the wrong way to use two DBs here?

Here is **settings.py**, the second db called `dataset` is the one i'm trying to use:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'dataset': {
        'NAME': 'dataset',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password goes here'
    }
}
```

Here is the model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    num = models.Float()

    def save(self): # ALL the signature         
        super(SomeModel, self).save(using='dataset')
```

And here is the form:

```
class DataForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ("data", "num")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        send = super(DataForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            send.save()
        return send
```

Since i added the line `using="dataset"` shouldn't the data be sent to the `dataset` db? Or am i doing something else wrong? Any advice is appreciated!

**Edit**: i tried migrating the second database using `manage.py migrate --database="dataset"` but i get the error `The connection dataset doesn't exist`

Comment: Did you run `manage.py migrate` on the secondary database?

Comment: @JohnGordon Check my last edit!

Comment: Did the secondary database exist in `settings.py` when you originally ran `manage.py makemigrations`?  Or did you add it later?

Comment: Later @JohnGordon

Comment: Then I think that's your problem.  When you add new databases/models, you have to rerun both `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Comment: Yeah, i tried doing makemigrations and then migrate, but even that doesn't work

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" is no help.  What happened, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, i'm getting 'database="dataset" does not have migrations". In the meantime i still get the error 'table does not exist'

Comment: Ok, i think i solved the problem. Basically i was trying to migrate the database with a WRONG name. Only issue that i found is that when i migrated, i had all the tables and the data from the default DB copied in my second DB. Do you know why that happened @JohnGordon?

Comment: I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quote `'`. 
Try this

```
super(SomeModel, self).save(using='dataset')
```

You can lookup this [Multi DB Save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save)

Comment: My bad, it was a typo when copying the code. The line is correct in my original code, just made a mistake when creating the question